# Is implementation of a standard constructor (Java) necessary in this case?

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

I have three classes like this:

```
public abstract class ClassA extends ClassX {
    protected ClassA() {
        super();
    }
    // more code
}
public class ClassB extends ClassA {
    public ClassB() {
        super();
    }
    // more code
}
public abstract class ClassC extends ClassB {
    public ClassC() {
        super();
    }
    // more code
}
```

I would say that the standard constructor for `ClassC` is not necessary since Java will insert it during compilation, since there is no other constructor in this class, right?
If true, I could simplify the code for `ClassC` down to this:

```
public abstract class ClassC extends ClassB {
    // more code
}
```

Now I'd say that I can't do the same for `ClassB` since the accessibility of the constructor is increased from `protected` to `public`.

I'm asking since I am not 100% sure about this and thought I might be missing something. Especially about the standard constructor that will be inserted into `ClassC` if I don't implement it myself. In this case it will have accessibility `public` since it inherits from `ClassB`. Is that correct?

So my question is: Can I delete the constructor in ClassC without having the code being changed (especially the accessibility of constructors) and is it correct that I can't delete the constructor of ClassB.

Comment: You probably should ask separate questions :)

Comment: Long story short. Your assumptions seem correct

Comment: You're right :-). So my question is mainly: Can I delete the constructor in ClassC without having the code being changed (will edit the question).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this:
> Now I'd say that I can't do the same for ClassB since the accessibility of the constructor is increased from protected to public.

Default constructors are package private.

Comment: @RazvanManolescu: If the default constructor is package private, that would either mean, if I delete the constructor of ClassC, java will not add a default constructor, since it can't have lower accessibility (package private), or it will add a constructor that is not package private but public (since it must be equal or higher than it's parent). Which one would you say does Java insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now I'd say that I can't do the same for ClassB since the accessibility of the constructor is increased from protected to public.

That's irrelevant, given that it's an abstract class. The constructor can't be called directly - it's only used when chaining from a subclass constructor.

So while it would be *technically* different, your code would be *effectively* the same if you removed all the constructor declarations.

But in terms of the accessibility of default constructors, [JLS 8.8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) is the authority here:

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor is implicitly declared. The form of the default constructor for a top level class, member class, or local class is as follows:
>
> - The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class (§6.6).
> - ...

Comment: "The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class" --> that helps a lot, thank you very much!

Comment: My confusion was due to the fact that I thought the default constructor inherits the accessibility of the no-argument, no-throws-statement constructor of its parent class. Since the documentation says it inherits the accessibilty of *the class itself*, it's clear now.

Comment: Good remark about ClassA being abstract - you're right, then I can also remove the constructor there. Wondering who put it there to begin with :-)

Answer (score 1):

> The rule that the default constructor of a class has the same access modifier as the class itself is simple and intuitive. Note, however, that this does not imply that the constructor is accessible whenever the class is accessible.

1. If you do not make a constructor, the [default empty constructor is automatically created](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).
2. If any constructor does not explicitly call a super or this constructor as its first statement, a [call to super() is automatically added](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7).

> That means if your constructors are defined with in the scope of the child class then there is no need to call `super()` explicitly. As in your case you can remove all the constructors. Your program will still compile and run.

Hope this helps. For more please have a look at the shared links, it has some more beautiful examples.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java specification on default constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9).

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor with no formal parameters and no throws clause is implicitly declared.
>
> If the class being declared is the primordial class Object, then the default constructor has an empty body. Otherwise, the default constructor simply invokes the superclass constructor with no arguments.

So you should be good with not including any of those constuctors.